# Select and upload a file to a specific folder

Tags: c#

I need to upload one selected file to a specific folder. I have this code:

```
using System.IO;

namespace FTP_UPLOAD
{
    public partial class FTPUPLOAD : Form
    {
        public FTPUPLOAD()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var fileContent = string.Empty;
            var filePath = string.Empty;

            using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
                openFileDialog.Filter = "zip files (*.zip)|*.zip";
                openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
                openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    //Get the path of specified file
                    filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

                    //Read the contents of the file into a stream
                    var fileStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show(fileContent, "File Content at path: " + filePath, MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

I needed to define where the file will be uploaded to (like c:\ftp). After the process was completed, I wanted to show the user the full path to where that file is located, like (filename = file.zip) than: ftp.mysite/file.zip

Comment: So what is your problem? What do you get & what did you expect?

Comment: I can select the file, but I need to copy it to that folder (c:\ftp). When it finishes, display the path of that file.

Answer (score 0):

To copy the file, you can use:

```
File.Copy(openFileDialog.FileName, "c:\\ftp\" + openFileDialog.SafeFileName,true);
```

Comment: Please confirm which answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the SaveFileDialog class after you obtain the path of the file you want to save. Add `using System.IO;` to use the FileInfo class.

```
private void SaveFile(string filePath)
{
  FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);

  using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog())
  {
    saveFileDialog.FileName = filePath;
    if( saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Your file was saved at " + saveFileDialog.FileName);
    }                
  }
}
```